# Would this work to dynamically embed a PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, file-exists

So would like to look up a pdf in my directory with a part number (pnumber) and if it is there, I would like for it to embed it but if it is not, I would like for a defeault pdf to be embeded.  Would the code below be the correct way of doing so?

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            echo $_POST['pnumber'];
        ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Search: <input type="text" name="pnumber">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Find Alert">
    <br />
</form>
        <?php
        $filename = '/PDFs/pnumber.pdf';

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<p>
        <embed src="PDFs/$filename.pdf" width="100%" height="400" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http//www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html" />
    </p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>
        <embed src="PDFs/QAAlert.pdf" width="100%" height="400" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http//www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html" />
    </p>";
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: did it work - if yes it's the correct way, if not explain the problem

Comment: No it did not work I got this back... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'PDFs' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\QAlert\index.php on line 79

Comment: next time include that when you ask the question.

Comment: thank you, I will look at the solutions to my error.